# Azure Table storage to Azure Table storage using Azure Data Factory using DateTime Parameterized query

Tags: parameter-passing, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Table storage where a few records are added every day (usually 3-5).  There are days when no records can be added, so the volume is very low.  Here is the structure of table with the pre-defined PartitionKey, RowKey, and Timestamp columns:

[image: Screenshot showing Data in Azure Table]

I need to query this table from the Azure Data Factory for the previous day's records.  So for the example data shown below, I could be querying for 2019-04-25 data on 2019-04-26.  The reason being, one day's staleness does not make a difference and that way, I don't have to worry about 'Watermarks' etc.  I simply query for the data for the previous day and copy it to an identical Azure Table in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2.

I know that I need to specify a parameterized query based on the 'Timestamp' column for the previous day but do not know how to specify it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set query sql in the copy activity table storage source.For your needs,it should be like:

```
time gt datetime'2019-04-25T00:00:00' and time le datetime'2019-04-2T00:00:00'
```

My sample data as below:

[image]

Preview data as below:

[image]

Pls see some examples in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage#azuretablesourcequery-examples.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually I had opened up another thread, which went beyond this and got the help that I needed there.  Here is a link to that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463256/how-to-specify-query-for-azure-data-factory-source-azure-table-storage-for-yes

Comment: @Bharat Ok,maybe i miss that.Thank you for your sharing.