# How to specify query for Azure Data Factory Source (Azure Table Storage) for yesterday's records

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am copying records from an Azure Storage Table (source) to Azure Storage Table (sink) everyday. So if I am executing the query on December 24th 2019 (UTC) for instance, then I want to copy records for December 23rd 2019 (UTC).  The query works and is doing what I intend it to do. Here is the query:

```
Timestamp ge datetime'2019-12-23T00:00Z' and Timestamp lt datetime'2019-12-24T00:00Z'
```

In the query above, the Timestamp column is automatically stamped in the Azure Storage Table when a new record is inserted in it. That is how Azure Storage Table works.

And here is the screenshot of the Data Factory Pipeline:

[image]

I want to parameterize the query now. That is: if the query is run on 24th December, 2019 then it should copy 23rd December 2019's records and keep sliding as it executes everyday on a schedule. I don't know how to do that. I know that there is a utcNow function and there is a subtractFromTime Function.  I just don't know how to put it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()), -1)
```

this would find the start of the previous day

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions

Comment: I am assuming that you want me to substitute my query expression with:  Timestamp ge addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()), -1) and Timestamp lt startOfDay(utcNow()) ?  I did that but the preview fails with the message: Request.StorageExtendedMessage=An unknown function with name 'utcNow' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.

Comment: how about this: `"Timestamp ge datetime toString(addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()), -1)) and Timestamp lt datetime toString(startOfDay(utcNow())"`?

Comment: Tried.  No luck.  Here is the response: Request.StorageExtendedMessage=Syntax error at position 30 in 'Timestamp ge datetime toString(addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()), -1)) and Timestamp lt datetime toString(startOfDay(utcNow())'. RequestId:a172e768-5002-008d-150e-ba03f5000000 Time:2019-12-24T03:58:29.6662023Z, The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 3):

@4c74356b41, Thank you for your kind support.  Based on your answers and some more googling, I was able to piece it together.  Here is the final expression:

```
Timestamp ge @{concat('datetime','''',addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()), -1),'''')} and Timestamp lt @{concat('datetime','''',startOfDay(utcNow()),'''')}
```

Comment: upvoting helpful answers helps, you know :)